# Spark SQL - Array of arrays to a single array

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I have two columns with arrays of strings

```
| ColA | ColB |
|------|------|
| ["a"]| ["b"]|
```

I wanted to create a single column containing values from both of the arrays"

```
| ColAplusB |
|-----------|
|["a", "b"] |
```

I tried `array(ColA, ColB)` which left me with:

```
| ColAplusBnested |
|-----------------|
| [["a"], ["b"]]  |
```

How could I get the desired result (array of arrays conversed to an array of values from initial arrays)?

Comment: Search for term `flatten array/collection`. I don't know spark, but I believe it should be doable without custom code.

Comment: I believe flattening reduces it to single value per row, which is not exactly what I am looking for. `explode` does that, but then I am not sure how to pick all values back into a single array.

Comment: I mean something like `flatten(array(ColA, ColB))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's suppose your data is like this:

```
val df = spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(
  (Array("a"), Array("b")) 
)).toDF("ColA", "ColB")
df.printSchema()
df.show()

root
 |-- ColA: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- ColB: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)

+----+----+
|ColA|ColB|
+----+----+
| [a]| [b]|
+----+----+
```

The [existing set of Spark SQL functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html) doesn't appear to have a concatenation function for arrays (or sequences). I only see `concat` functions for strings. But you can create a simple user-defined function (UDF):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

val concatSeq = udf { (x: Seq[String], y: Seq[String]) => x ++ y }
val df2 = df.select(concatSeq('ColA, 'ColB).as("ColAplusB"))
df2.printSchema()
df2.show()

root
 |-- ColAplusB: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)

+---------+
|ColAplusB|
+---------+
|   [a, b]|
+---------+
```

Any extra logic you want to perform (e.g. sorting, removing duplicates) can be done in your UDF:

```
val df = spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(
  (Array("b", "a", "c"), Array("a", "b")) 
)).toDF("ColA", "ColB")

df.show()

+---------+------+
|     ColA|  ColB|
+---------+------+
|[b, a, c]|[a, b]|
+---------+------+

val concatSeq = udf { (x: Seq[String], y: Seq[String]) =>
  (x ++ y).distinct.sorted
}

df.select(concatSeq('ColA, 'ColB).as("ColAplusB")).show()

+---------+
|ColAplusB|
+---------+
|[a, b, c]|
+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Spark 2.4.0, the [array_union](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#array_union) function has allowed for the concatenation of two arrays. Note that this will deduplicate any values that exist in both arrays.

If you want to combine multiple arrays together, with the arrays broken out across rows rather than columns, I use a two step process:

1. Use [explode_outer](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#explode_outer) to unnest the arrays.
2. Use [collect_set](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#collect_set) to aggregate the values into a single deduplicated array. If you do not wish to deduplicate your results, use collect_list instead.